# How to use HtmlUnitDriver with application using jquery 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, selenium, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to automate the flow of a website which has a jquery sweet alert.
When I use HtmlUnitDriver for headless browser testing then the sweet alert is considered as not visible.
So when I tried to execute javascript to change div display to 'block' then I get some exceptions.

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.someurl.com");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;     
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('dummy').style.display= 'block';");
WebElement dummy = driver.findElement(By.id("dummy"));
System.out.println("dummy is displayed?:"+dummy.isDisplayed());
```

Exception with HtmlUnit 2.18 with Selenium Webdriver 2.48.2 :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function createHTMLDocument in object [object DOMImplementation]
```

Answer (score 1):

This special issue was fixed with [HtmlUnit 2.22](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a2.22) but in general you have to switch to the latest version (2.27 at the moment).

Comment: Using HtmlUnit 2.22 threw following exception:  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.dnsResolver   on line driver.get("https://www.someurl.com")

Comment: Please use `2.27`, WebDriver/HtmlUnit